# loading relationship with groupBy laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a query which selects some relationships and groups by the accommodations to remove the duplicate accommodations. But now when I want to load the `discount` realtion on rooms, it doesn't work because I select only the `accommodation_id`.

Here is my code:

```
 $data = AccommodationRoom::with('accommodation.city', 'accommodation.accommodationFacilities', 'accommodation.gallery','discount')
        ->select('accommodation_id')
        ->whereHas('roomCapacityHistory', function ($query) use ($from_date, $to_date) {
            $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
            $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
        })
        ->whereHas('accommodation', function ($query) use ($searchCity) {
            $query->where('city_id', $searchCity);
        })
        ->groupBy('accommodation_id')
        ->get();
```

Now if I add the `id` to the select it would be fine, but my `groupBy` doesn't work and gives me an error in this case. So I need a solution to get all my accomodations with the listed relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are looking for all your accommodations with some related models, you should actually select from your `Accommodation` model. This will work out of the box for the first three relations but will require some tweaking for the `discount` relation. The simpliest solution is to create a `HasManyThrough` relation on the `Accommodation` model:

```
class Accommodation extends Model
{
    public function discounts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Discount::class, AccommodationRoom::class);
    }
}
```

*Note: this expects your models to use foreign key columns named by convention; for different names you will need to pass the custom foreign key names as additional parameters [according to the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).*

With this relation set up, you can then use a query like the following:

```
$data = Accommodation::with('city', 'accommodationFacilities', 'gallery', 'discounts')
    ->whereHas('accommodationRooms.roomCapacityHistory', function ($query) use ($from_date, $to_date) {
        $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
        $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
    })
    ->where('city_id', $searchCity)
    ->get();
```

---

Further explanation as asked for in the comments:

`HasManyThrough` builds a *virtual relation* between two models using a third model in between. Imagine you have `Post`, `Comment` and `Like` as models. One `Post` can have many `Comment`s and one `Comment` can have many `Like`s:

```
            has many                       has many
Post   ----------------->   Comment   ----------------->   Like
       1                n             1                n
```

In this case we also know that one `Post` can have many `Like`s. And this is exactly the knowledge we utilize when using `HasManyThrough`. We simply tell Eloquent that a `Post` has many `Like`s, connected by the `Post`s in between:

```
            has many                       has many
Post   ----------------->   Comment   ----------------->   Like
       1                n             1                n


                   has many through Comment
Post   ------------------------------------------------>   Like
       1                                               n
```

Comment: its working but idk how really :) i read the documenation but i dident get it can you please tell me what hasManyThrough doing ?

Comment: @Farshad I added an additional explanation to my answer. Hope the ascii art helps you to understand it better.